# Boolean comparison of two Series objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Series which have a format equal to this:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    True
Name: foo, dtype: bool

0    True
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    True
Name: bar, dtype: bool
```

I want to create a new Series with the resulting boolean comparison from these. Something like this:

```
result = foo and bar
>>> print result
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    True
Name: result, dtype: bool
```

Using the obvious `result = foo and bar` simply results in the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I looked at those functions, but neither seem to do what I wish.

**How can I do an element-to-element boolean comparison of a Series resulting in a new Series?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the bitwise and operator `&`.

```
result = foo & bar
```

Comment: When comparing dataframe's column to a certain value and then performing a boolean comparison, you need to use parenthesis. For instance, `df['column1'] != 'a' & df['column2'] != 'b'` will generate the error `cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]`. On the other hand, `(df['column1'] != 'a') & (df['column2'] != 'b')` will work just fine